# vs2107 building from the command line "The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0."

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I can't build a vs2017 solution from the command line, but I can build from the IDE. Once I've built from the IDE the command line build will work. So the ide is doing something different - what am I missing? Here is what I do for the command line build:

```
nuget.exe restore mysoln.sln
"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /m /t:Rebuild /clp:Summary /p:Configuration=Debug  /p:Platform="Any CPU" mysoln.sln
```

The output I get:

```
"Forms.csproj" (Clean target) (14:3) ->
     E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(126,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0.  Either target .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.0. [E:\wp\Forms.csproj]
```

Any ideas how I can make the command line build work?

==============

## Update

I tried `"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /m /t:Restore GpsConsole.sln` from the command line and it works. But when jenkins runs the exact same command i get the same error

==============

## Update 2

The way we got the solution building was :

```
nuget.exe restore mysoln.sln
"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /m /t:Restore  mysoln.sln 
"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /m /t:Rebuild /clp:Summary /p:Configuration=Debug  /p:Platform="Any CPU" mysoln.sln
```

Comment: I believe the flag for restore is just `msbuild.exe /restore GpsConsole.sln`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rethink you command-line approach.

You can make your build script independent of Visual Studio installation, make it using MSBuild version you want, and reusable on a build server.

**Short plan**

1. Install Visual Studio Build Tools 2017
2. Find proper MSBuild
3. Clean solution
4. Restore packages
5. Build solution

---

**Details**

1. Using Build Tools will give you independence from Visual Studio installation.

   Download [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15) from [Visual Studio Downloads page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) ([direct link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/7/C37763CB-E533-4290-BE34-1DF89C218CFE/vs_BuildTools.exe))

   Command-line arguments documented here: [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](http://Use%20command-line%20parameters%20to%20install%20Visual%20Studio%202017)

   All workloads and components are listed here: [Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools)
2. You can use PowerShell module `VSSetup`. Download it or install from here: [Github: Microsoft/Visual Studio Setup PowerShell Module](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell)
3. Just run MSBulid with `clean` target
4. Help `nuget.exe` to use proper MSBuild
5. Run MSBuild with `build` target (you can add additional required parameters)

---

```
# 1. Find MS Build  

Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\VSSetup\VSSetup.psd1

$msBuildPath = (Get-VSSetupInstance | Select-VSSetupInstance -Version 15.0 -Product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools).InstallationPath

if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 8)
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64'
}
else
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin'
}

Write-Output "Using MSBuild from $global:msbuildPath"
Write-Output "MSBuild /version"

$msbuild = Join-Path $global:msbuildPath msbuild

& $msbuild /version


# 2. Clean

& $msbuild "$sln_file" /t:Clean /v:q /nologo


# 3. Restore

$nuget = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\.nuget\nuget.exe"
& $nuget restore -MSBuildPath $global:msbuildPath


# 4. Build

& $msbuild "$sln_file" /t:Build /v:q /nologo
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your visual studio does have the .net core 2.0 SDK installed, since it is able to build your .net standard 2.0 solution.

But, nuget restore is pointing to an sdk inside the visual studio directory (one of a few that visual studio can use,  but not where .net core 2.0 sdk installs to by default).

Your .net core 2.0 sdk is likely located in C:\...\dotnet\...

You'll want to have nuget restore use the msbuild located inside that directory, rather than the one within the visual studio directory.

Comment: makes sense, how do i get nuget to use the correct msbuild?